# Should a server-backed app show time according to the device’s clock or the server’s clock?

Tags: time

The current time can be different across different computers. For example, a user may adjust the clock on their mobile device or personal computer whereas server clocks are generally always synced with an accurate time service.

Some use cases that I can think of where a user may adjust the clock:

- Make the clock run early to compensate for the user’s tendency to be late.
- Work around time-based limitations in apps (e.g. games).

---

Which clock should a server-backed app use when displaying times?

As a concrete example, consider a hypothetical app with a Do Not Disturb function that is synced across multiple clients via a server. The server performs the Do Not Disturb function by preventing notifications from being sent to clients. In the app, the user can configure the end time of the Do Not Disturb period using a date picker control.

Should the time that the user specifies be based on the device clock or the server clock? If the time is based on the server clock, then the time value would be sent as-is to the server. If the time is based on the device clock, then the time value would be adjusted to be based on the server clock using a clock synchronization algorithm before being sent to the server.

---

My opinion is that all times displayed by a device should be based on the device clock; otherwise, having the ability to adjust the device clock would be sort of pointless. What do y’all think?

Comment: Hey, can the user choose the time zone on the app? If yes, I think it would make sense to have the app translate the server time to each person's time? In that way you have the "true time" (server) and the user-friendly time that users can understand.

Comment: @MikeMark The time zone isn’t the issue; the issue is the actual time on the device. For example, the server time might be 4 PM but the user might have adjusted the device clock to be 3:45 PM.

Comment: If you have users choosing their time zones, then the times you display are the times of the server adjusted for timezone, when times on device is different for more than 4 minutes tell them "Time on server and device do not match"

Comment: There, you can give users the option to 1. either see the time adjusted from server to timezone + difference or see the real-time Does that make any sense? :).

Comment: Why server can't translate this 4 minutes as well? I mean user can see it as his own time. If you setting do not disturb period, then definitely it would be weird if it wouldn't be sync with your clock. You say no notification till 15:00, and then it is "14:57" and you are getting notification. That would be annoying.